# Change gcc compiler executable name in BJam

Tags: bjam

How to change compiler executable name? I want to perform a "fake build" of some products which are using BJam as build system. (For example: the Boost itself) In this "fake build" I want some special command to be called instead of g++. (with all the options and environment used in real build with real gcc).
How to perform this? Are there any command line switches which already allows me to do what I need or maybe I can somehow modify *.jam files to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 4):

The easiest thing might to just switch your path so gcc refers to what you want to run.  Otherwise, the correct way to do it bjam is more finicky.  I've never gotten it to successfully, easily work, but here's what the docs suggest:

You'll need to add command to the Jamroot of your project to configure the gcc mocking command.  The simplest way is just:

```
using gcc : : my-gcc ;
```

But most likely you have another `using gcc ;` line somewhere in your jam rules (or site-config.jam) and you'll get a complaint about trying to reinitialize a toolset.  If so, you'll need to give an explicit version to the toolset like so

```
using gcc : mywrapper : my-gcc ;
```

And to use this toolset when compiling use the command `bjam toolset=gcc-mywrapper`.

Good luck.